# prevent user ID on address bar

Tags: php, html

the link below is from one of my webpages to  display specific user profile when the view button is clicked but the problem is that it displays the user id on address bar which I think is not good practice for security issues how can this be prevented but achieve the desired output?

HTML button

```
<button><a href="view.php?member_id=<?php echo $roww['member_id'];?>">View</a> </button>
```

the php code from view.php file

```
if (isset($_GET['snippet_id'])) {
    $snippet_id = $_GET['snippet_id'];

    try {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM snippets WHERE snippet_id = :id');
        $stmt->execute([':id' => $snippet_id]);
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use some form of hash value instead, nevertheless it will still have to identify the particular user uniquely.

Comment: You can define a type of slug for each user
or encrypt and decrypt the ID

Comment: It's unclear why you think this represents a security risk? Your system needs to know which user to display. That always involves some type of ID.

Comment: **Your HTML is invalid.** An anchor cannot be the child of a button element. Fix that first.

Answer (score -1):

You can define a type of slug for each user or encrypt and decrypt the ID.

I will explain encryption and decryption to you here:

```
<?php
    $seed = time().rand(100,999);
    $hashedMemID = base64_encode($seed.$roww['member_id']);
?>
<a href="view.php?member_id=<?php echo $hashedMemID;?>">View</a>
```

php file:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['member_id'])) {
    $decodedMemberID = base64_decode($_GET['member_id']);
    $memberID = substr($decodedMemberID,14);
```

And you can use $memberID

Comment: code does not work